# Returning an object which is inside an array of another object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am connecting to an api and returning some data on screen using the below:

```
return (

    <>

        {Object.values(items).map((item, index) => {
        return <pre>{JSON.stringify(item, null, 2)}</pre>

    </>

})}
```

This returns an object to the front end that looks like this.

```
[
  {
    "type": "player",
    "id": "account.ac12c743e8044d42a6eafeffa2c3a8cf",
    "attributes": {
      "name": "JohnnyUtah",
      "stats": null,
      "titleId": "pubg",
      "shardId": "stadia",
      "patchVersion": ""
  },
  "relationships": {
      "assets": {
      "data": []
  },
  "matches": {
      "data": [
      {
        "type": "match",
        "id": "473019a4-fe3b-420a-b00e-b99ff2cd8c73"
```

I would like to as an example get just the id as shown below:

```
"id": "account.ac12c743e8044d42a6eafeffa2c3a8cf"
```

However I have an object with an array of objects inside of it and I don't know how to access this.

I am familiar with the array map function which I believe I need to use, but I don't know how to get inside that array in the object being returned.

I'm therefore struggling to see how I get at this value.

---

Adding full code as this may help clarify things:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

function Player() {

  const [player,setPlayer] = useState('JohnnyUtah')
  const [items,setItems] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {

    const apiKey = "key";

    const options = {
      "headers": {
        "Accept": "application/vnd.api+json",
        "Authorization": `Bearer ${apiKey}`
      }
    }

    fetch(`https://api.pubg.com/shards/stadia/players?filter[playerNames]=${player}`, options)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => setItems(json))

  }, [player])

  return (
    
    <>
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => setplayer('JohnnyUtah')}>JohnnyUtah</button>
        <button onClick={() => setplayer('Binder')}>Binder</button>
        <button onClick={() => setplayer('MartinSheehanUK')}>MartinSheehanUK</button>
      </div>
      <h1>{player}</h1>

      <div>

      <h2>This shows all</h2>
      {data.map((item) => (
          <li key={item.id}>{item.id}</li>
        ))}
      </div>
      
      <div>
      <h2>This shows only one</h2>
      {data[0].id}
      </div>

    </>

  ) 

};

export default Player
```

Just showing the absolute latest version of my code which is still not returning any results for me:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

function Player() {

  const [player,setPlayer] = useState('JohnnyUtah')
  const [items,setItems] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {

    const apiKey = "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJqdGkiOiI5MTI0M2U5MC1iMjk5LTAxM2EtN2Q5ZC0xNzRhYzM1YTM1ZGYiLCJpc3MiOiJnYW1lbG9ja2VyIiwiaWF0IjoxNjUyMTkyMTI4LCJwdWIiOiJibHVlaG9sZSIsInRpdGxlIjoicHViZyIsImFwcCI6InB1YnJnLWxlYWRlcmJvIn0.veCjNiRtCzchj2Gli-aZt_0YQjtMvey3io-UUDa0zpQ";

    const options = {
      "headers": {
        "Accept": "application/vnd.api+json",
        "Authorization": `Bearer ${apiKey}`
      }
    }

    fetch(`https://api.pubg.com/shards/stadia/players?filter[playerNames]=${player}`, options)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => setItems(json))

  }, [player])

  return (
    
    <>
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => setPlayer('JohnnyUtah')}>JohnnyUtah</button>
        <button onClick={() => setPlayer('Binder')}>Binder</button>
        <button onClick={() => setPlayer('MartinSheehanUK')}>MartinSheehanUK</button>
      </div>
      <h1>{player}</h1>

      {items !==undefined && items.length>0 ? items.map((item) => (
        <li key={item.id}>{item.id}</li>
      )): <div>No result found</div>} 
 

    </>

  ) 

};
```

Comment: Why `Object.values`? Why not just `items[0].id` for the first or `items.map(item => item.id)` for all? You didn't show an object with an array of objects in it, you just showed an array of objects.

Comment: Do you want to get only the first item's id? In that case you might use `items[0].id`, but if you want to get all, you can use `map` to loop through all array objects and get the id as `item.id`

Comment: It could be also good to share the API you are using so I could generate scenario for it.

Comment: Thanks @NijatMursali the api can be found here: https://documentation.pubg.com/en/introduction.html

Comment: I will have a look, but do you want to get only one object's id or all of them?

Comment: @NijatMursali both would be great. I think if it was just an object or just an array, I'd be alright but returning an object that has an array of objects is throwing me.  Thanks.

Comment: Please check my answer. I am sure it is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all `id`s from array of objects like

```js
const data = [
  {
    type: "player",
    id: "account.ac12c743e8044d42a6eafeffa2c3a8cf",
    attributes: {
      name: "Steve1989",
      stats: null,
      titleId: "pubg",
      shardId: "stadia",
      patchVersion: ""
    },
    relationships: {
      assets: {
        data: []
      }
    }

    //some other values
  },
  {
    type: "player",
    id: "account.bc24c743e8044d42a6eafeffa2c3a8cf",
    attributes: {
      name: "John133",
      stats: null,
      titleId: "pubg",
      shardId: "stadia",
      patchVersion: ""
    },
    relationships: {
      assets: {
        data: []
      }
    }

    //some other values
  }
];


const App = props => (
    <div className="App">
    <div>
    <h2>This shows all</h2>
    {data.map((item) => (
        <li key={item.id}>{item.id}</li>
      ))}
    </div>
    
    <div>
    <h2>This shows only one</h2>
    {data[0].id}
    </div>
      
    </div>
);

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

I have also attached the solution to get only specific index.

**Update:**
The issue is happening with your array where you have to set `setItems(json.data)`. You also need to check if your array is defined.

Full code:

```
function Player() {
const [player,setPlayer] = useState('JohnnyUtah')
const [items,setItems] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {

    const apiKey = "your_key";

    const options = {
      "headers": {
        "Accept": "application/vnd.api+json",
        "Authorization": `Bearer ${apiKey}`
      }
    }

    fetch(`https://api.pubg.com/shards/stadia/players?filter[playerNames]=${player}`, options)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => setItems(json.data))

  }, [player])
  return (
    <>
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setplayer('JohnnyUtah')}>JohnnyUtah</button>
        <button onClick={() => setplayer('Binder')}>Binder</button>
        <button onClick={() => setplayer('MartinSheehanUK')}>MartinSheehanUK</button>
    </div>
    <div>
    {items !=undefined && items.length>0 ? items.map((item) => (
        <li key={item.id}>{item.id}</li>
      )): <div>No result found</div>} 
    </div>
  </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Still can't get this working as I get the following error > Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined which looks like I'm trying to work with an array when I actually have an object. Have included full code in case that helps here.

Comment: `data` is your `items` array. Please replace it and try again. I will update my code as well if it does not work

Comment: Now I get this error: Player.js:44 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')

Comment: I updated the code and tested it myself. It should be working fine now. Just copy and replace the code inside your `Player` component. Let me know if it works.

Comment: It does not return any value if you select platform to `stadia`, I selected it to `steam`. I have also tested in API itself, in `stadia` you don't have these names.

Comment: Thanks Nijat, have updated those usernames to Stadia compatible ones. The one I am working with is 'JohnnyUtah' now.  The code is no longer showing any errors but always returns the 'No result found' message?

Comment: Are you sure you changed the `steam` to `stadia` in link? It works in my case and returns id.

Comment: Hope my solution helped you. If it works, please accept it as accepted answer. Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249790/discussion-between-johnny-and-nijat-mursali).

Comment: you forgot to change `.then(json => setItems(json.data))`, just change `setItems(json)` to `setItems(json.data)`

Answer (score 0):

Assign stringify data to the variable and then you can convert JSON stringify data into parse data using this: JSON.parse then fetch the data:

Below is the example:

```
const obj = {name: "John", age: "30", city: "New York"};

const myJSON = JSON.stringify(obj);
var c = JSON.parse(myJSON);

console.log(c.name);
```

Please try it and let me know if you find any issue

Comment: Why you exactly change the age to `string`, stringify the object and again change it to json?

Comment: Nothing, it's extra code, I have removed it.